# Disable editing local-storage data in angular

Tags: angular, local-storage

Are there any method or way to **disable editing local-storage data** using the browser developing tools and is it more secure to use cookies over local-storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to prevent user from editing local storage because local-storage is on clients browser and it's a web browser's option.So we can't restrict user to access his or her browser features from server side.